# Single Choice List Item Does not Populate

Tags: android, listview, layout, radio-button

I'm building a single choice list with a button at the bottom, and I can't seem to get the text in the actual list to display. Basically, it's a simple implementation that looks like:

```
public class SetPrefsActivity extends ListActivity{ 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radiolist);
    ArrayList<Hall> listItems = new ArrayList<Hall>();
    ArrayAdapter<Hall> ar = new ArrayAdapter<Hall>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, listItems);
    setListAdapter(ar);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    { ... //stuff});

    ...

    //((ArrayAdapter<Hall>)getListAdapter()).add(stuff)
    ...
}
```

And Xml for radiolist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/theButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click to go to next Activity"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I see is a black area where the list should go, and then my button under it. Before I added: `setContentView(R.layout.radiolist);` it showed the populated list just fine. How do I get it to show up in this layout?

Sorry I'm just getting into android!

Comment: Using `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the `ListView` in a vertical `LinearLayout` means the width will literally be `0dp` as `android:layout_weight` will only affect the vertical dimensions. Set `android:layout_width` to be `fill_parent`. Also, you need to fill your `ArrayAdapter` before calling `setListAdapter(...)`.

Comment: wow, i feel stupid; thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Along with changing your width, you should add : `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Here is a link that might help: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Otherwise, when you scroll, you will get black boxes and other unwanted results when you scroll with your list.